# React ES6 components are not re-rending

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code. Please notice the two `console.log`s. I am calling the `_getChartData()` function from within another child of the `<ChartTitle>` component.

The issue is that when `_getChartData()` is called a second time, it doesn't re-re-render the child components of the code below. I am expecting it to do so because of the `setState` in there.

```
export default class PerformanceChart extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { chart_data: [] };
        this._getChartData();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._getChartData();
    }

    _getChartData(d = 30) {

        console.log('running setState for chart data');

        // AJAX GOES HERE
        this.setState = ({
            chart_data : [ 
                ['x', '2016-01-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01'],
                ['Clicks', Math.random(), 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 125, 600],
                ['Orders Reported', 300, 250, 100, 400, 150, 250, 40, 300],
                ['totals', [1050, 5042]]
            ]
        });

    };

    render() {

        console.log('re-rendering!');

        return (

            <div>
                <ChartTitle chart_data={this.state.chart_data} getChartData={this._getChartData.bind(this)} />
                <Chart chart_data={this.state.chart_data} />
            </div>

        );
    }

};
```

This is what I get in my console:

[image: My console logs]

Comment: When are you running _getChartData except componentDidMount?

Comment: @IlanHasanov from within the child components within the render: `getChartData={this._getChartData.bind(this)} `

Comment: Could you share all the code ? //AJAX GOES HERE show this.setState() add all code of all components please

Comment: @IlanHasanov Sure, I've uploaded it here: https://gist.github.com/nyalex/76250b929411d3f4c32eb81d44c98523

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is your problem

```
this.setState = ({
```

`setState` is a function, you need to call it not assign it, i.e.:

```
this.setState({
    chart_data : [ 
        ['x', '2016-01-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01'],
        ['Clicks', Math.random(), 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 125, 600],
        ['Orders Reported', 300, 250, 100, 400, 150, 250, 40, 300],
        ['totals', [1050, 5042]]
    ]
});
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver! Spent all day on this! Can't believe I had missed that. Thanks so much! Here's some <3.